# substring in sqlserver with casual format

Tags: sql-server, substring

I have these rows

```
14-L-100-10008-G03S-N
1-DR-100-20057-G48-N
2-CL-100-12133-B12-P
2-FG-100-12202-B01-N
2-G-100-15520-B48-N
2-GM-100-10024-B01-N
2-HC-100-10022-G03S-N
2-HC-100-10023-G03S-N
2-HC-100-20023-G03S-N
32-G-100-15518-F03P2-N
32-G-100-15518-F03P2-N
```

I just need these parts .how can i get these parts using sql server code  :

```
result:G03S,G48,B12,B01,B48,B12 and ...
```

Comment: @NEER no as you can see sometimes N or PT not specific format

Comment: The only patter I see is between the 2nd last and last minus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can as the below:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
select '14-L-100-10008-G03S-N' Val UNION ALL
select '1-DR-100-20057-G48-N' Val UNION ALL
select '2-CL-100-12133-B12-P' Val UNION ALL
select '2-FG-100-12202-B01-N' Val UNION ALL
select '2-G-100-15520-B48-N' Val UNION ALL
select '2-GM-100-10024-B01-N' Val UNION ALL
select '2-HC-100-10022-G03S-N' Val UNION ALL
select '2-HC-100-10023-G03S-N' Val UNION ALL
select '2-HC-100-20023-G03S-N' Val UNION ALL
select '32-G-100-15518-F03P2-N' Val UNION ALL
select '32-G-100-15518-F03P2-N'
)

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Val), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val), 0) + 1, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val), 0) + 1) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val)) - 1)) 
FROM
    CTE
```

Edit:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Val), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val), 0) + 1, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val), 0) + 1) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val)) - 1))  + ' ,'
    FROM
        CTE
    FOR XML PATH ('')
) Result
```

Result: `G03S ,G48 ,B12 ,B01 ,B48 ,B01 ,G03S ,G03S ,G03S ,F03P2 ,F03P2 ,`

```
SELECT LEFT(A.Result, LEN(A.Result) -1) FROM 
(SELECT (SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Val), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val), 0) + 1, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val), CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val), 0) + 1) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Val)) - 1))  + ' ,' FROM CTE FOR XML PATH ('') ) Result) A
```

Result: `G03S ,G48 ,B12 ,B01 ,B48 ,B01 ,G03S ,G03S ,G03S ,F03P2 ,F03P2`

Comment: How can i merge my query with your query ?here is my query :select  LineNumber from Lines

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Updated

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the [splitstring functions from here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)..

```
create table #t
(
id varchar(max)
)

insert into #t
select '14-L-100-10008-G03S-N'
union all
select '1-DR-100-20057-G48-N'

select item
 from #t t1
cross apply
(select * ,row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by t1.id) as rn from [dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](t1.id,'-')
) b
where rn=5
```

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'dbo.SplitStrings_Numbers'.